# Can't boot into external SSD with Ubuntu on it on laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd

I installed Ubuntu on an external SSD by manually specifying partitions (530MB for EFI, rest ext4 with some free space inbetween and at very beginning of volume) and it boots fine on the original PC that I used to create it with. Even though the external SSD worked on that system, when I plug it into my laptop it doesn't detect it as a boot device in the BIOS (Asus Zenbook). So I can't even get to the grub to update it or change it, etc. Just for reference, when I tried installing Ubuntu by erasing the disk and doing the automated install (removed all other boot devices in the PC), it seems to work okay. Any idea on why this might be happening?

Comment: Ubuntu cannot change what the BIOS is willing to boot from.

Comment: Ubuntu's Ubiquity only installs grub2's UEFI boot files into the first drive. Normally that is the internal Windows drive's ESP. And external drives only boot from a drive entry using /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, like installer but full version of grub. You can copy /EFI/Boot & /EFI/ubuntu (both required) to external drive from internal drive. The from UEFI of another system should be able to choose the drive to boot. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379